# An alternative valediction to "godspeed" wishing someone success in a venture

Tags: salutations, valediction, religion, correspondence

I am essentially searching for a well-wishing exclamation that does not imply divine intervention.

Comment: Try "good luck"

Comment: Live long and prosper. \V/_

Comment: How about *Success!*?

Comment: Go get 'em, tiger.

Comment: @Jim Good call...though for people in the know, that line is older than Star Trek....all the way back to a religious statement ;)

Comment: "Go get 'em, tiger." is intimate and informal. While it may be appropriate, it is a lazy, crude expression.

Comment: "You're so-o-o good-lookin'."

Answer (score 9):

"Goodbye" is derived from God be with you, as are many valedictions.

"Take care" is sort of threadbare.
"Farewell" seems antiquated.
"Bon Voyage" is great if you're French.
*Be well*,  *good fortune*, *until we meet again*
I do like the Vulcan Valediction, live long and prosper.

**Namaste** is very respectful. It is spiritual, however; it can be interpreted (roughly) as a way of saying "Not-myself to you" (a benevolent expression of both respect and impersonality). It has some good karma to it.

May the road be downhill all the way to your door.

May your days be many and your troubles be few. May peace be within you may your heart be strong. May you find what you're seeking wherever you roam.”

May the road rise up to meet you, may the wind be ever at your back. May the sun shine warm upon your face and the rain fall softly on your fields, until we meet again

Comment: "May the road rise up to meet you" is nice, but full version ends with the words "...and until we meet again, may God hold you in the palm of His hand". It's a religious blessing based on a prayer, so probably not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @toryan - the ending need bot be used. However, May... implies some beneficient force, so may not be appropriate anyway.

Comment: On the other hand, _May the road rise up to meet you_ sounds like you're wishing that I fall flat on my face.

Comment: @terdon - lol, it does, doesn't it? Well, may the road be downhill all the way to your door, then, and may the path be dry.

Answer (score 4):

There are many expressions of felicitations, to wish happiness, congratulations, longevity, success, or encouragement, that can be found in common use and that don't invoke a religious sentiment. I found [this link](http://www.islandireland.com/Pages/folk/sets/bless.html), which seems to illustrate quite a few, some of which I quote here:

> May you see your children's children.
>
> May you be poor in misfortunes and rich in blessings.
>
> May you know nothing but happiness from this day forward.
>
> May the road rise up to meet you.
>
> May the wind always be at your back.
>
> May the sun shine warm upon your face, and rains fall soft upon your fields.

A common French expression that sometimes finds its way into English is **bon courage**, which might translate into **keep a stiff upper lip**, or **hang in there**, or simply **you can do it**.

Of course there is my half-joking comment above, which is **live long and prosper**. This, according to [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/live-long-and-prosper.html) originated as a Jewish religious blessing, but became more popular in Star Trek as the Vulcan salutation (along with the Vulcan hand salute.)

The same reference at Phrase Finder also equates this with the similar Hebrew phrase *Shalom aleichem* and the Arabic phrase *Salaam alaykum* that roughly translate to **peace be upon you**. This phrase was mentioned by others here.

As you can see, despite the fact that some of these phrases originated within a religious context, the words themselves, in many cases, are neutral toward religion.

Update

And in the same vein with the Star Trek reference, there is also **may The Force be with you**, which is an areligious Star Wars phrase probably borrowed from "may the Lord be with you". (Unless you subscribe to the notion that there is a religious cult aspect to The Force within the Star Wars universe.)

Comment: The list you quote contains a lot of dereligified versions of biblical blessings (e.g. *may you live to see your children's children* Psa 128:6; shine upon your face is taken from Numbers 6:8). Don't know if that pleases the asker.

Comment: I took a narrower interpretation of the OP's question. Since the OP is looking for phrases "that don't imply divine intervention", I think that doesn't rule out phrases that stand on their own (no divine intervention expressed or implied), even if they were, at some time, used in a religious context. But, yes, some atheists, for instance, may be more comfortable with some of my examples than with others.

Answer (score 2):

"Good luck" seems the most straightforward, and it might be a good place to start searching online thesauri if it's not *exactly* what you're going for.

Comment: In Pagan religions, good luck or fortune is also a religious invocation, as you are invoking a minor deity to give you the luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try, "Bon voyage!", "Peace be with you," "Farewell," or "Fare thee well." No divine intervention there. Also, "Good luck!" as mentioned by Kevin.

If you were a Spartan, "May you live forever," was actually the opposite, as the greatest glory a Spartan could achieve was dying in battle [1].

*[1]: Source - [300](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vrPY15CYqc)*

Answer (score 1):

How about 'break a leg'. It is traditionally for actors and actresses but I've heard it used commonly.

Answer (score 0):

A ambiguity in your question is what you mean by well-wishing. Deity-based well-wishing presumably involves *wishing* that the deity would grant that wish. Thus, a question is whether you want to continue *well-wishing* in some other way and to what end or whether you just mean to say *I care about your success*.

I've heard people with this concern who want to move away from well-wishing to warm sentiments say *sending warm thoughts your way*.

If you want to stick with your original sentiment, you could just say *speed you!* I don't know what it would mean, but you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

British soldiers say good luck by saying;

Stay low, move fast.